# cannot await for generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

i have an interface to make service to make async actionresult
 here is the code of the interface and the class

```
       public interface Ienter
{
   List<Page> AddPages(string path, Book book);
}


public class enternew :Ienter
{

    private graduationEntities db = new graduationEntities();
    List<Page> temp = new List<Page>();


    public List<Page> AddPages(string path, Book book)
    {
        ///////////
        return temp;
    }
}
```

and here is the controller

```
     public class BookController : Controller
    {
    Ienter _ienter ;
    public BookController (Ienter ienter)
    {
        this._ienter = ienter ;
    }
      [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult>  Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Url,CategoryID")] Book book)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        string path = "";
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        book.Url = path;
        List<Page> pages = new List<Page>();
        pages = await this._ienter.AddPages(path,book);
        return View(book);
    }
```

at the await the compiler told me that cannot await because it returns for generic collection

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to wait the `AddPages` method? It is not an asynchronous method.

Comment: Change your interface to include `Task<List<Page>> AddPages(...)` and make the implementation follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the signature of the interface, you can instead wrap the call to the implementation in a `Task.Run`:

```
pages = await Task.Run(() => this._ienter.AddPages(path, book));
```

This uses an anonymous delegate to call your method.

A more important question is what benefit you think you're deriving from awaiting your `AddPages` method - just because async/await is the new hotness doesn't mean everything benefits from being retrofitted.

Comment: there is a long code to add many pages to this list it cannot be sycronous  so i can add two books at the same time with thier pages thnx sir for helping me

Comment: sir i have another problem that said there is no parameter in the constructor of the controller which i defined it for dependecy injection to make that so can you help me?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have one method that accepts a params collection of Books? Most ORMs (assuming you're using one) have bulk add/remove methods. Entity Framework, for instance, has AddRange and RemoveRange functions - since the longest part of the operation tends to be establishing a connection, bulk inserts, etc., tend to be faster.

Comment: For your last comment - you need to ask another question - DI has nothing to do with your current question.